# Android 4.0 Design Guidelines and Backwards Compatibility

Tags: android, android-fragments

Google has a great resource for [Android 4.0+ Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html). But there is still a large percentage of Android [users running 2.3.x](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

What is the easiest way to use the latest design guidelines while still maintaining backwards compatibility with older OS versions?  There are a lot of special menus and navigation tools in the guidelines that are probably Android 4.0+ only. Do they gracefully fall back to basic elements for older versions of the OS? Do you have to create a whole separate view/template for each major Android version?

What is the best approach to adopting the newest guidelines with leaving a large percentage of users out in the cold?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Factionbarsherlock.com%2F&ei=EUWQUOT-BKXmiwLN5oHgDQ&usg=AFQjCNEKyOYK1H-iAiI67o4J8dIPJNL9TA&sig2=bBemH9Of9AkgJ6uiBJhwZA) and the [HoloEverywhere](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FChristopheVersieux%2FHoloEverywhere&ei=HEWQUL6iEaGcjAK43oD4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHjHK7GWfkXusOoRZ6dh3X4VXYCTg&sig2=MmcuMrDALTMnyCAeY2Xzjg) libraries, as well as the [Android Support](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There is a support library from google ([link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)) that ports back many of the Android 4 UI Features. You may look at the feature list on their homepage for details.

Furthermore, there is Actionbar Sherlock by Jake Wharton. This a is an extension to the Compatibility Actionbar that offers more features than the original from google. ([link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/))

Answer (score 0):

"Do you have to create a whole separate view/template for each major Android version?"
The answer for this is No, All you need is a single apk for all the Android versions,
But the UI would be changed depending on the OS version and screen size.
Android provides a number of support libraries for doing this.
The latest design guidelines are compatible only for Android 3.X (Honeycomb) and higher.
For the earlier versions, the UI would behave accordingly.
Please go through Android documentation about support libraries, and there you can find some samples too.

But if you want the same look for all the versions of Android, then you have to go for third party libraries like Actionbar Sherlock.